# Does Bitcoin Core version v22.0.0 support SLIP-0132?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, output-script-descriptors

1. Launched my own Bitcoin Core with regtest.
2. Installed Specter and made it connect to that node.
3. In Specter, I created a new bitcoin wallet, basing it on the bitcoin core hot wallet.
4. In Specter, I exported an extended public key:

`[cf308846/84h/1h/0h]vpub5YK...`

5. Now, when I try to `getdescriptorinfo` with bitcoin, it says: "key 'vpub5YK...' is not valid".
6. The argument values I tried for `getdescriptorinfo` are:

   6.1) `wpkh(vpub5YK.../0/*)`

   6.2) `wpkh([cf308846/84h/1h/0h]vpub5YK...)`

   6.3) `combo(vpub5YK...)`

Either I am doing someting wrong, or bitcoin core 22 simply does not understand `SLIP-0132` addresses.

Answer (score 5):

No.

The supported [key expressions](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0380.mediawiki#user-content-Key_Expressions) in the descriptor language are:

- Individual public keys in hexadecimal
- xpubs as defined in BIP32, possibly followed by a key derivation path
- Individual private keys in WIF
- xprvs are defined in BIP32, possibly followed by a key derivation path

The zpub/ypub/vpub were extensions designed with a similar intent as the descriptor language itself, trying to convey how the keys are to be used. That role is more completely covered by e.g. the `wpkh()` you're using, so no need to add it to the public key encoding.